# In Snowflake, does "Load Table" functionality require target table to be created by the same user/role that does the load?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have defined a MANUAL schema into which we would like to create tables that are loaded "manually" by users through the web ui tables >> table >> Load Table functionality.

The DDL part should be done by dba, but then when ever the data needs to b changed then the according user could make the change.

We have then the schema, the role and user, the example "DUMMY" table, the file format (CSV) ready(all defined by the dba), also the manual load user is then granted DML rights on the table . But then the table load fails:

```
There was an error while trying to stage "DUMMY.csv".
Reason: SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on table stage 'DUMMY'
```

So can we somehow grant the table stage to the manual load role/user? Or we need to grant DDL rights so the table needs to be created by the same user that loads data into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see, it's not possible to grant any privilege on a table stage. **Please someone correct me if I'm wrong!**

As a workaround, you may revoke existing privileges of the role, and then change the ownership of the table:

```
revoke all on table DUMMY from role MANUAL_ROLE;
grant ownership on table DUMMY to role MANUAL_ROLE;
```

I assumed that you have role named MANUAL_ROLE which is assigned to users.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Snowflake Managed stages:

```
grant read on stage DUMMY to role MANUAL_ROLE;
grant write on stage DUMMY to role MANUAL_ROLE;
```

This is only if the stage is not of type Snowflake Managed and is connected to a non-Snowflake storage location on AWS, Azure, or GCP:

```
grant usage on stage DUMMY to role MANUAL_ROLE;
```